# Pixel Art size for different resolutions

Tags: 2d, libgdx, pixel-art

What size I should make the UI elements (mostly buttons). How do pixel graphics look good on all resolutions? How would I get to know what size I need the buttons or other pixel graphics overall?

Comment: I believe the best way is to pick a resolution for your game, say 320x240, and size all of your graphics based on this. Then in your game, simply keep the viewport at that resolution regardless of the window size to keep everything looking nice.

Comment: While we can't decide your asset sizes for you, we can share some methods & considerations. Check out [this blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/), which talks about using padding/cropping and multiple asset sizes in combination to support a variety of resolutions. The upshot is "all resolutions" is probably not an achievable goal for pixel-perfect graphics. Establishing a set of resolutions that matter most for your game is a good first step. An image mocking up your "target" look will also help.

Comment: Ah, here it is: The Great White Buffalo, also known as graphics scaling. Short answer? There is no good way to do it. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. I went to pure 3D because of this very reason, and it still creeps back up for UI design.